# extracting the data through python script in paraview

Tags: python, paraview

How to extract data from plot data filter in paraview through python script?? I want to get data through python script by which paraview is drawing the graph.
If anyone know this answer please help
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually plots are made by plotting one data array versus another. You can often obtain that data directly from the filter/source that produced it and save it to a CSV file. To do this, select

You can save data from a filter as a CSV file by selecting the filter/source in the Pipeline Browser and choosing File -> Save Data. Choose the CSV File (*.csv) file type. Arrays in the filter/source output are written to different columns in the CSV file.